# How to Remove Virtual Input/Output Device 'BoomAudio' on MacOS Ventura 13.6.1?

Tags: macos, audio

I'm facing an issue with a virtual input/output device called 'BoomAudio' on MacOS Ventura 13.6.1.

This virtual input/output was for an app that was removed months ago, but the virtual peripheral still appears and sometimes gets selected in Sound settings, resulting in no input or output. How can I remove this device and resolve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You should have uninstalled from inside the running app itself.

If you have Boom 3D, there's a separate [uninstaller](https://www.globaldelight.com/boom3d/mas-content/uninstall.php) available.

For Boom 2 either re-install the app then follow the instructions in [How do I uninstall Boom 2?](https://www.globaldelight.com/faq/boom2/?source_page=GD_FAQ_page#10)

…or

1. Check for any files related to Boom in:

   - `/System/Library/Extensions`
   - `~/Library/Extensions`
   - `/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins`
   - `~/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins`
     & delete.
2. Delete Boom app [if you didn't already].
3. Reboot.
4. Confirm that BoomDevice has been removed from System Sound Preferences.